# ZendFramework comments box and relational databases

Tags: zend-framework, phpmyadmin

I am new to the Zend Framework and this is my first project, I have a list of clubs that when clicked it takes you to a description page of the club you specified. I then want a comments box for this club on the description page. I have a comments table, user table and clubs table in my database, all these tables will have to be linked by a foreign key so that I can see what club the comment is for and which user posted the comment. The problem I am having is understanding which keys will be foreign keys and how to do this in phpmyadmin. Once this is set up I am then wondering how to implement this in the ZendFramework does any one know of any useful materials online that I could read relating to this sort of issue?

Thanks

Rik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set your database use [Zend_Db_Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.db.adapter.html) to connect to your DB and define classes for each of your tables, extending the abstract class [Zend_Db_Table_Abstract](http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.db.table.html) as explained [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.defining) .

> I am then wondering how to implement this in the ZendFramework does
>   any one know of any useful materials online that I could read relating
>   to this sort of issue

Read [this tutorial](http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf) to get you started with ZF (it has an example similar to what your are trying to do) .

Take a look also at [Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) which will help you retrieve data from your database .
and [Zend_Db_Table Relationships](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html) is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

In a table a foreign key is an "id" that is not the primary key of the table , so if you have 2 tables , clubs and comments , then
in comments table , the foreign key would be the club_id column so you can refer to the club primary key.

You should take the time to learn how a Zend Application is structured , check the documentation on ZendFramework website.